# Facebook graph: Post picture as page not as user

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using FB App to publish posts to my FB pages. 
So when i use this code for links, it works.

```
 $facebook = new Facebook(array(
 'appId' => $fb_app_id,
 'secret' => $fb_secret,
 'cookie' => true
));

$attachment =  array(
        'access_token' => $row["token"],
        'name' => $_POST["name"],
        'picture' => $_POST["picture"],
        'message' => $_POST["message"],
        'link' => $_POST["link"]);
    try
    {
        $facebook->api("/".$row['id']."/feed", "POST", $attachment);
    }

    catch(Exception $e)
    {
         echo('exception caught '.$e->getMessage());
    }
```

But, when i want to share pictures as a page:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
     'appId' => $fb_app_id,
     'secret' => $fb_secret,
     'cookie' => true,
     'fileUpload' => true,
     'allowSignedRequest' => false 
    ));  

$attachment =  array('access_token' => $row["token"], 'url' => 'http://image.link.jpg', 'message'  => $_POST["message"]);
            try
            {
                $facebook->api("/".$row['id']."/photos", "POST", $attachment);  
            }
            catch(Exception $e)
            {
                echo('exception caught '.$e->getMessage());
            }
```

The app post picture as user. USER to PAGE. 
So i found that i need to use publish_pages permission, but my access token contains both publish_actions and publish_pages. I can't change that because I'm using one access token for a lot of things.

[image]

So i have to ask, is there a way to explicitly choose what permissions i want to use from access token. FB API have same code for page and user picture publish /user_id/photos and /page_id/photos.

Comment: You need to use a page access token instead of the user access token. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to use Page access token, there's no other way.